# Difference between a BLOCK and a function in terms of scoping in Perl

Tags: perl, variables, scope

Guys I'm a little bit confused, I was playing with scoping in Perl, when i encountered this one:

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub nested {
   our $x = "nested!";
}

print $x;     # Error "Variable "$x" is not imported at nested line 10."
print our $x; # Doesn't print "nested!"
print our($x) # Doesn't print "nested!"
```

But when i do this:

```
{
   our $x = "nested";
}

print our($x);  # Prints "nested"
print our $x;   # Prints "nested"
print $x;       # Prints "nested"
```

So guys can you explain to me why those works and not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To explain why the block example works the way it does, let's look at `our` explanation from ["Modern Perl" book, chapter 5](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_05.html)

   > **Our Scope**
   >
   > *Within given scope*, declare an alias to a package variable with the our builtin.
   >   The fully-qualified name is available everywhere, but the lexical alias is visible only within its scope.

   This explains why the first two prints of your second example work (our is re-declared in print's scope), whereas the third one does not (as our only aliases $x to the package variable within the block's scope). Please note that printing `$main::x` **will** work correctly - it's only the alias that is scoped to the block, not the package variable itself.

   ---
2. As far as with the function:

   - `print our $x;` and `print our($x)` "don't work" - namely, *correctly claim the value is uninitialized* - since you never called the function which would initialize the variable. Observe the difference:

     ```
     c:\>perl -e "use strict; use warnings; sub x { our $x = 1;} print our $x"
     Use of uninitialized value $x in print at -e line 1.

     c:\>perl -e "use strict; use warnings; sub x { our $x = 1;} x(); print our $x"
     1
     ```
   - `print $x;` won't work for the same reason as with the block - `our` only scopes the alias to the block (i.e. in this case body of the sub) therefore you MUST either re-alias it in the main block's scope (as per `print our $x` example), OR use fully qualified package global outside the sub, in which case it will behave as expected:

     ```
     c:\>perl -e "use strict; use warnings;  sub x { our $x = 1;}  print  $main::x"
     Use of uninitialized value $x in print at -e line 1.

     c:\>perl -e "sub x { our $x = 1;} x(); print  $main::x"
     1
     ```

Comment: but what about in the function's scope?

Comment: @BelmarkCaday - you didn't wait till the second edit :). BTW, I omitted strict/warnings in last command simply because SE's formatting created horizontal scoller because of too-long string.

Comment: @DVK : `$ perl -Mstrict -we '...'`

Comment: @Zaid - `-w` is not the same as `'use warnings'`. Caveat user :)

Comment: @GregD'Arcy : Could you give an example where the two differ in behavior?

Comment: @Zaid - Per [perllexwarn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html#What's-wrong-with-*-w*-and-%24%5eW) `-w` enables warnings globally, whereas `'use warnings'` is appropriately scoped. Although not directly relevant to the brief examples in the original (and summarised to generalities to keep it short), `-w` will cause other included modules to emit warnings and `'use warnings'` will not. Your original comment could also have advocated `-Mwarnings` instead of `-w`, which is 3 characters shorter than `'use warnings;'` and still directly equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

To restate DVK's answer, `our` is just a handy aliasing tool. Every variable you use in these examples is actually named `$main::x`. Within any lexical scope you can use `our` to make an alias to that variable, with a shortened name, in that same scope; the variable doesn't reset or get removed outside, only the alias. This is unlike the `my` keyword which makes a new variable bound to that lexical scope.